# Schedule ECS Task from AWS Lambda in Python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, lambda

I need to schedule my ECS Task from AWS Lambda in python. I need the lambda handler code for this. How do I run aws task in python?

Comment: U can use the boto3 python package http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ecs.html

Answer (score 0):

```
import boto3

ecs_client = boto3.client('ecs') 
logger = logging.getLogger()

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    response = ecs_client.run_task(
        cluster='your-cluster',
        taskDefinition='your-task-name',
        count=1,
        launchType='EC2', # or fargate
    )

    logger.info(response)

    response = {
        "isBase64Encoded": "false",
        "statusCode": 200,
        "headers": { "COntent-Type": "application/json"},
        "body": "hello"     
    }

    return response
```